# Access AWS API Gatway Endpoint with API Key in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an API endpoint with API key that I am trying to read some data from the endpoint using Python with boto3. How can I do this?

I read the boto3 [APIGateway](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html) and it is not helpful and I am lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boto3 SDK is used for managing (create, delete, update) your API Gateway settings.

To actually call and use the resulting API as an enduser you need to use regular http tools, such as `curl` for command line use, [postman](https://www.postman.com/) for more user friendly experience or [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library for Python

Comment: thank you! This seems like the solution. I am not quiet sure how to give the API key in `request.get`. I am getting `403 forbidden` error. Is there a working example with API keys that you can direct me?

Comment: For api keys, you need to specify them in headers. [Here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) is generic example of doing that in `requests`. For exact headers, have to check aws docs on api gateway.

Comment: is the header specific to API Gateway, meaning when API Gateway endpoint was set up, header also gets defined? If so, I can ask the person who sent me Gateway Endpoint URL and API Key about how those specific headers work.

Comment: Yes. For the api key, the header is: `X-API-Key: value`